# AttributeError: 'Coin' object has no attribute 'Coin'

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

I'm importing `coin.py` into my `main_game.py` as follows:

`import coin`

`coin.py` contains a single class `Coin`, which takes no additional arguments. Here are the contents of `coin.py`:

```
class Coin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("gold.png").convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.bump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("coin.wav")

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

When I try to instantiate objects of this class as follows:

```
coin = coin.Coin()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev_projects\python\pygame_projects\final_project\main_game.py", line 39, in <module>
    coin = coin.Coin()
AttributeError: 'Coin' object has no attribute 'Coin'
```

Initial research suggested an issue with indentation, so I recreated the small class and saved in a new file and deleted the old file. I got the same issue.

Next, I renamed `coin.py` to `treasure.py`, updated my `main_game.py` file and the problem disappeared. I renamed it to `coi.py` to test that and that also worked without issue. When I renamed the file back to `coin.py` the issue re-appeared.

Again, I didn't fiddle with any kind of indentation here, just renamed `coin.py`. I'm OK to move forward because I have a workaround but I'm wondering what on earth gives to cause this problem with the specific name coin?

Any idea what the issue with `coin.py` could be? Here's `help(coin)` when the file is named `coin.py`:
Help on Coin in module coin object:

```
class Coin(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
 |  simple base class for visible game objects
 |
 |  pygame.sprite.Sprite(*groups): return Sprite
 |
 |  The base class for visible game objects. Derived classes will want to
 |  override the Sprite.update() method and assign Sprite.image and Sprite.rect
 |  attributes.  The initializer can accept any number of Group instances that
 |  the Sprite will become a member of.
 |
 |  When subclassing the Sprite class, be sure to call the base initializer
 |  before adding the Sprite to Groups.
 |
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Coin
 |      pygame.sprite.Sprite
 |      builtins.object
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __init__(self)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from pygame.sprite.Sprite:
 |
 |  __repr__(self)
 |      Return repr(self).
 |
 |  add(self, *groups)
 |      add the sprite to groups
 |
 |      Sprite.add(*groups): return None
 |
 |      Any number of Group instances can be passed as arguments. The
 |      Sprite will be added to the Groups it is not already a member of.
 |
 |  add_internal(self, group)
 |
 |  alive(self)
 |      does the sprite belong to any groups
 |
 |      Sprite.alive(): return bool
 |
 |      Returns True when the Sprite belongs to one or more Groups.
 |
 |  groups(self)
 |      list of Groups that contain this Sprite
 |
 |      Sprite.groups(): return group_list
 |
 |      Returns a list of all the Groups that contain this Sprite.
 |
 |  kill(self)
 |      remove the Sprite from all Groups
 |
 |      Sprite.kill(): return None
 |
 |      The Sprite is removed from all the Groups that contain it. This won't
 |      change anything about the state of the Sprite. It is possible to
 |      continue to use the Sprite after this method has been called, including
 |      adding it to Groups.
 |
 |  remove(self, *groups)
 |      remove the sprite from groups
 |
 |      Sprite.remove(*groups): return None
 |
 |      Any number of Group instances can be passed as arguments. The Sprite
 |      will be removed from the Groups it is currently a member of.
 |
 |  remove_internal(self, group)
 |
 |  update(self, *args)
 |      method to control sprite behavior
 |
 |      Sprite.update(*args):
 |
 |      The default implementation of this method does nothing; it's just a
 |      convenient "hook" that you can override. This method is called by
 |      Group.update() with whatever arguments you give it.
 |
 |      There is no need to use this method if not using the convenience
 |      method by the same name in the Group class.
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from pygame.sprite.Sprite:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

So, I can call help on the coin file, which tells me it has a class Coin, but even if I try to instantiate it in the interpreter it throws:

```
>>> coin = coin.Coin()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    coin = coin.Coin()
AttributeError: 'Coin' object has no attribute 'Coin'
```

Is there some kind of interference coming from `pygame`, perhaps?

Comment: Almost certainly a "namespace collision" i.e. you have another variable inside your code called coin that python thinks you are talking about rather than the module coin.

Comment: Rather than sharing the "help" which ironically isn't helpful for answering your question, share a simple executable example of some code that has the same problem.

Comment: Where you do `coin = coin.Coin()` seems like a good place for a namespace collision. You are overwriting the module coin with a variable called coin.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, put this code in a loop? Then consider - the first time through the loop, you make `coin` **stop** being a name for the `coin` module, so that it can be a name for the just-created object **instead**. So, what will happen the **next** time through the loop?

Comment: Yes scotty and Karl you are both correct. A for loop instantiates a Coin object but since it gets assigned to the variable coin the coin.py import gets overwritten. Crystal clear now, thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are declaring a new variable called coin and then you are trying to access the Coin class from it. This means that the file is no longer associated to the variable coin and therefore cannot access the Coin class.To have the file named coin.py you need to rename your variable coin to something else.

Comment: Interesting. Renaming the coin object to the_coin worked, and makes total sense in retrospect...But that opens another question. I do something very similar with a Player class:

player = player.Player(20, 15, screen_height, screen_width)

That line works without issue. Is that because the Player class takes arguments?

Comment: But wait...I can create a simple Dog class in a file named dog.py:

class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dog"

I can call that from another file like so, no problem:

import dog

dog = dog.Dog()

Why doesn't that cause the interference you're describing?

Comment: I see the problem now based on what I've done in my code. Since the coin is in a loop, the first creation of the coin object does in fact remove the reference to the coin file. The problem happens when coin.Coin() is called again. In my dog.Dog() test, I didn't call it in a loop, which was why I didn't see the problem even though it was still there.